# Changing application.properties in AWS for a Spring Boot webapp

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I've made a spring project using Boot. the project runs fine locally. It's a simple webapp connected to a mysql database. The configuration path is:

**src/main/resources/application.properties**

With parameters like this:

```
spring.datasource.url = xxx
spring.datasource.username = xxx
spring.datasource.password = xxx
```

Now, I've deployed the app in AWS without problems. I've configured the database already but when the app tries to start I'm getting this error:

*The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.*

I guess that is using my local configuratión file that was packed in the war file. Now, how can I change those values in the AWS? O do I need to pack the war with the correct **application.properties** in that server?

Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, you can use yaml files, specify both local and dev/qa/prod environment configurations, and not have to swap any files out, and just specify the environment at the command line.

Comment: @Compass but how to tell Elastic BeanStalk to use certain dev/stage/prod profile?

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience, best way of handling this is by creating properties files for each environment. I.e:

```
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
application-test.properties
```

and then prior to build just switch spring.profiles.active in your application.properties file to dev, prod or test.

If your are still getting this error once your configuration is ok, my advice is to check does ip address of your deployment server should be authorized on production db instance in order to connect.

Comment: I think the question asked is "how" to do that. How to switch profiles on AWS elastic beanstalk.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

There are several methods of setting configuration outside your JARs resource, pick the one that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, we can use spring cloud config server along with hosted properties on repositories like git/svn and pull them on the fly based on the active profile that you are running the application

Answer (score 0):

Below Solution is some one using cloud (not applicable to OnPrem - I wil lgo with application-{env}.properties).

**I will use application.properties and put properties across environments in AWS AppConfig.**

This answer is specific to someone using AWS :

1. Have application.properties for properties across environments.
2. Create an application in AWS AppConfig.
3. Create Environment like local,dev, uat and Prod in AWS AppConfig.
4. Create Freeform configuration profile-> AWS AppConfig Hosted Configuration->Choose format i.e. text/json/YAML.
5. Provide your environment specific properties.
6. Deploy It.
7. You need to define APPCONFIG_PROFILE,APPCONFIG_ENVIRONMENT and APPCONFIG_APPLICATION dynamically in application.properties :

my-service.aws-app-config.profile=${APPCONFIG_PROFILE}

my-service.aws-app-config.environment=${APPCONFIG_ENVIRONMENT}

my-service.aws-app-config.application=${APPCONFIG_APPLICATION}

7. Have docker file :

   "java","-Xms256m","-Xmx1G","**-Dspring.profiles.active=${ENV}**","-jar","app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"